# How to narrow down the <keyof object> in typescript

Tags: typescript

I have one case in which I need to narrow down the type from bigger type to smaller as shown below

```
interface abc {
  a: string;
  b: string;
  c: number;
  d: string;
  e: string;
}
var a: Array<keyof abc> = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"];

interface abcd {
  b: string;
  c: number;
  d: string;
  e: string;
}

//Error
var b: Array<keyof abcd> = a.filter((data) => data !== "a");
```

Here it gives me an error

```
Type '(keyof abc)[]' is not assignable to type '(keyof abcd)[]'.
  Type 'keyof abc' is not assignable to type 'keyof abcd'.
    Type '"a"' is not assignable to type 'keyof abcd'
```

Is there any way to tell to compiler 'a' will not be there via typescript without using

Answer (score 0):

You know `ts` compiler does not know about the result of callback function of filter. The compiler only look at the type of `a.filter(data=>data!=='a')` that is `(keyof abc)[]`.

But in this case, we know more than `ts` compiler that `a.filter(data=>data!=='a');` is the same as `(keyof abc)[]` so, simply we can use `type assertion`:

```
var b: Array<keyof abcd> = a.filter(data=>data !== 'a') as Array<keyof abcd>
```

[PlaygroundLink](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=22&ssc=77&pln=22&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAjgIwQbwFDL6gLgGcwpQBzAbl3zWNIuv2QQJAFcBbNaJ-AE3pkQVGnghDG2AL7YAbnCiFkAQShQ4ATwA8AawiaA9jFQYAfAF5kAbQDkcWwBpbaJ7YRv%20biLYC61bGxQSFhEFHQEfhxmMWQ6EmFRZlYObl5YwQSpZgkskWpZeUVkEys4ADoYYAAbEIAKfjgwOAszRubkAEILK3tbAEoAgHohgFF1QygipTpVdS09A2NTSLNkMsqa%20vaWtqa4Lp7kPv7UIjmNHX0jEwj%20MyA)

Comment: yes @Alireza this I know but dont we have any way in type script the way we have partial for object some like that.

Comment: What is wrong with `as` keyword. It has solved your problem.